# How do you determine if a user has IIS installed based on the registry?

Tags: iis

I have a program that needs to check if the user has an IIS service installed and then perform some actions.
I would like to know if the user has installed IIS and version number through the registry.
Which registry value should I access?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages in order to familiarize yourself with the site. Please do so, especially [ask], before posting your next question here. Simply writing a short question in the title and then repeating it as the only content in the body isn't going to work. Once you've read that page, come back and [edit] your post to clearly explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp